# Convert js object array into associative array

Tags: javascript, arrays

By using array.push() I'm updating a following array. I want to add index/key to every object in the object array as I want to check is a record exist with same index/key before pushing new item.

My array is like

```
$data = [
  {
    "id": 37,
    "permit_id": 1,
    "document_description": "zzxc",
    "file_name": "zxc"
  },
  {
    "permit_id": "1",
    "document_description": "aa",
    "file_name": "az"
  },
  {
    "permit_id": "1",
    "document_description": "aax",
    "file_name": "azx"
  }
]
```

and i want to convert this like

```
[
    0 => {
    "id": 37,
    "permit_id": 1,
    "document_description": "zzxc",
    "file_name": "zxc"
  },
    1 => {
    "permit_id": "1",
    "document_description": "aa",
    "file_name": "az"
  },
    2 => {
    "permit_id": "1",
    "document_description": "aax",
    "file_name": "azx"
  }
]
```

Is there any way to do this? please give me an idea.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no such thing as an associative array in JS. You need to convert it to an object.

You can use [`spread operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to convert the array to an object: `let myObj = {...$data}`

```js
let $data=[{id:37,permit_id:1,document_description:"zzxc",file_name:"zxc"},{permit_id:"1",document_description:"aa",file_name:"az"},{permit_id:"1",document_description:"aax",file_name:"azx"}];

let myObj = {...$data}

console.log(myObj);
```

**Update**

If you want to search the array to check if an object with a property already exists, you can use [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
let $data=[{id:37,permit_id:1,document_description:"zzxc",file_name:"zxc"},{permit_id:"1",document_description:"aa",file_name:"az"},{permit_id:"1",document_description:"aax",file_name:"azx"}];

let existingObj = {id:37,permit_id:1,document_description:"zzxc",file_name:"zxc"}
let nonexistingObj = {id:38,permit_id:1,document_description:"foo",file_name:"bar"}

if(!$data.some(item => item.id === existingObj.id)){
  $data.push(existingObj)
  console.log(`ID: ${existingObj.id} pushed`);
}else{
  console.log(`ID: ${existingObj.id} already exists!`);
}

if(!$data.some(item => item.id === nonexistingObj.id)){
  $data.push(nonexistingObj)
  console.log(`ID: ${nonexistingObj.id} pushed`);
}else{
  console.log(`ID: ${nonexistingObj.id} already exists!`);
}

console.log($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is basically what you have already. The array of objects is effectively an associative array where the keys are integers - both extend `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `forEach` loop. Array cannot have key and value pairs like objects so an extra object has to be made so as to keys the values with numbered keys

```js
var x=[
  {
    "id": 37,
    "permit_id": 1,
    "document_description": "zzxc",
    "file_name": "zxc"
  },
  {
    "permit_id": "1",
    "document_description": "aa",
    "file_name": "az"
  },
  {
    "permit_id": "1",
    "document_description": "aax",
    "file_name": "azx"
  }
]
var obj={};
x.forEach((e,j)=>{
obj[j+'=>']=e;
})
x=[obj]
console.log(x)
```

Comment: What you want is not possible. Arrays can't have key value pairs